# about Promise,this question below my me confused

Tags: promise

here is the code:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(0);
    return Promise.resolve(4);
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
            
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(1);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(2);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(3);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(5);
}).then(() => {
    console.log(6);
})
```

to me,I thought the answer would be 0;1;4;2;3;5;6.But the result is not.Why?

Comment: It has to do with the details of how promises enqueue `.then()` handlers, what sequence things get enqueued, what happens when you return a promise from a `.then()` handler and how promises wait until the stack unwinds before processing the job queue.

Comment: Nobody should write code that depends upon this level of detail.  If you want things from two different promise chains to get processed in a specific order, then you should be writing code that forces that to happen by using specific coordination between the two promise chains.  I used to write answers to these types of questions, but frankly the details of why are generally pointless for regular programming so I don't write these types of answers any more as it's really only a lesson in theory, not a lesson in how you should program.